# How to include PHP in Javascript; Google Chart API

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-visualization

I am working with the google chart visualization API.

I have a variable in php:

```
`$value`
```

which contains the following:
['0',0, 0],['1',65, 35],['2',88, 35],['3',66, 35],['4',35, 35],['5',99, 100]

I want to use this `$value` below in `data.addRows` as follows however the output I am getting is blank

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Period');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
    data.addRows([ 

   <?php echo $value ?>

            ]);

    var options = {
      width: 400, height: 240,
      title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

After some research it seems it is Ajax I am trying to attempt. Is this correct? Is there a simple way I can return the value `$value` to `data.addRow`??

Here is the process to which $value is set:

```
$i = "0";   
$period = "0";
$chartrow = array();
$unitpriceNumR = 3

while ($i<3)

{


$chartrow[$i] = "['".$period."',".$sPrice[$i].", ".$uPrice[$i]."]";


$period++;
$i++;

}

switch ($currentStage)
{

case "0":

$value = $chartrow[0];
    break;



case "1":

$value = $chartrow[0];  
    break;



case "2":

$value = $chartrow[0].",".$chartrow[1];
    break;


}
```

In this example if `$currentStage` = "2" then `$value` is set to ['0',0, 0],['1',65, 35]

Ok now I have even tried a copy and paste of google code into my file and still no success of seeing a graph. (code taken from:http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
    data.addRows([
      ['2004', 1000, 400],
      ['2005', 1170, 460],
      ['2006',  860, 580],
      ['2007', 1030, 540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      width: 400, height: 240,
      title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
 </script>
```

Using this code

```
$chartrow = array();


for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++ )
{
$chartrow[] = array((string) $i, $sPrice[$i], $uPrice[$i]);
echo $chartrow;

}
```

results in $chartrow displaying the word "Array" to the screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a PHP string to a Javascript variable (including escaping newlines)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines)

Comment: Think I may have found what is wrong.

Here is the code I am using: http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html

However when I hit Visualization Playground (link above the code), the code is structured different.

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to this problem
[PHP: How to pass multiple variables to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456868/php-how-to-pass-multiple-variables-to-an-array/8456924#8456924)

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at [the JSON encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function provided with PHP. This will let you `echo` or `print` out a **JSON encoded** string that JavaScript transforms into a native object.

```
$value = array(
    array('0', 0, 0),
    array('1', 65, 35),
    array('2', 88, 35),
    ...
);

...
data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
// Change this and the following lines to:
data.addRows(<?php print json_encode($value); ?>);
```

**EDIT**

```
$i = 0; 
$chartrow = array();
$unitpriceNumR = 3

for (; $i < 3; $i++ )
    $chartrow[] = array((string) $i, $sPrice[$i], $uPrice[$i]);

switch ($currentStage) {
    case "0":
    case "1":
        $value = $chartrow[0]; 
        break;

    case "2":
        $value = array_slice($chartrow, 0, 2);

    default:
        // You should have some default value, seriously!!!
}

// Then go the json_encode way, it's safer and easier to maintain!
...
data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');

// Change this and the following lines to:
data.addRows(<?php print json_encode($value); ?>);
```

Comment: ah maybe I am setting $value incorrectly. Right now it is set like one big string. Is that the problem?

Comment: Yepp, that is a problem, I suppose. Could you please post the part where `$value` is being set!

Comment: Ok, your approach is - hmm special. But as a quick fix (which I do NOT recommend) try `data.addRows(<?php print $value; ?>);` - without any brackets or surrounding function call.

Comment: ill try now, please see above, I fully show how $value comes about.

Comment: Does it do what it is supposed to, now?

Comment: graph is displaying now but with no data... data.addRows([ null ]); from view source When I use data.addRows([<?php echo json_encode($value) ?>]); in my code

Comment: Ill try your: data.addRows(<?php print json_encode($value); ?>); now

Answer (score 2):

Change `[<?php echo $value ?>]` to `<?php echo json_encode($value) ?>`

`echo $value` produces `Array(5)` because PHP doesn't natively know how to represent an array as a string.

`echo json_encode($value)` produces:

`[['0',0, 0],['1',65,35],['2',66,35],['4',35,35],['5',99, 100]]`

so you don't need brackets around the `<?php ... ?>`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

**EDIT:** thanks for clarifying how the PHP variables are formed.

The problem is that you're manually converting arrays into strings, when you should let `$json_encode` do all of the work for you.

Revised version of the PHP code:

```
$chartrow = array();
$unitpriceNumR = 3;

for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++)
    $chart_row[$i] = array($i, $sPrice[$i], $uPrice[$i];

switch ($currentStage)
{
    case '0':
    case '1':
        $value = $chartrow[0];
        break;

    case '2':
        $value = array($chartrow[0], $chartrow[1]);
        break;
}
```

**EDIT2:** I tried what you did (replacing the php block with what we expect the php block to produce) and it didn't work for me either. Firebug says 'Container is not defined' in Google's own code.

You forgot to add a `div` to your document. Add `<div id='chart_div'></div>` after the `script`.

So we're on the same page: http://jsfiddle.net/daemon/nnpeE/

Comment: ok I've done that and nothing is being outputted (no chart displayed). I am following this code http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html

Comment: ok so this is what I have data.addRows(<?php echo json_encode($value) ?>); but still no graph showing. The file is a php file. I have closed the php tags for the js...

Comment: What do you see when you view the source of the page? Does it show `data.addRows([['0',0, 0],['1',65,35],['2',88,35],['3',66,35],['4',35,35],['5',99,100]]);`?

Comment: it shows data.addRows("['0',0, 0],['1',65, 35],['2',88, 35],['3',66, 35],['4',35, 35],['5',99, 100]");

Comment: I suppose the problem is how I set $value

Comment: Try changing `echo json_encode($value)` to `echo json_encode($chartrow)`.

Comment: ill try now, please see above, I fully show how $value comes about.

Comment: Doesn't work...I even tried  data.addRows([['0',0, 0],['1',65, 35],['2',88, 35],['3',66, 35],['4',35, 35],['5',99, 100]]); and its not working...hmmm

Comment: See my edits. The script will work when you add the `div`. The php will (hopefully) work if you leave all the array-to-string conversion to `json_encode`.

Comment: data.addRows([ null ]); from view source When I use data.addRows([<?php echo json_encode($value) ?>]); The graph is showing but no data.

Comment: Again, the problem is setting $value. After using your code (I took away the underscore in $chart_row, and added a bracket in the same line to fix it up) when I echo $chartrow it outputs the word "array"

Answer (score -1):

Whenever I have values like that I do this as my first script on the page and it seems to work for me.  It also allows me to inspect what is going on with the PHP instead of the variable being hidden in some function.  Note that this will create a global variable which might be not what you want.

```
<script>
var a = [<?php echo($var1) ?>];
</script>
```

EDIT:
I got your PHP code to work for me.  The changes I made was I converted `$i` to just `0` not `"0"`  The same goes for the switch statement .  Also line 4 needs a semicolon after it.  Then I put this

```
<script>
var a = [<?php echo($value) ?>];
</script>
```

And the output in the page was

```
<script>
var a = [['0',, ],['1',, ]];
</script>
```

Comment: @afexx Well what I was thinking is then in the function he can put `data.addRows(a);` assuming '$var1` = `[...]`.  Obviously global variables are not optimal, but the OP can easily see what was outputted by PHP.